# Safe and smart http connection disconnect

Tags: android, okhttp

I have a few questions regarding the advised usage of OkHttp, in matters of connection disconnection and reuse. However the Android documentation on these issues is not so clear. So here they are:

1. Safe multi-thread disconnection:

(a) According to Android documentation: https://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html
HttpUrlConnection is not thread-safe.

However according to the author of OkHttp, the recommended way to terminate an active connection from a thread which is not the one actively using the connection, is by calling the `HttpUrlConnection.disconnect()` method: https://github.com/square/okhttp/issues/1842.

So can this API be safely called from a thread other than the one actively using the connection? Is it true for all OkHttp versions integrated into Android?

(b) After calling `disconnect()`, should we also manually close the InputStream as well by calling the close() API? or is this not required once disconnect was called?

2. Regarding socket reuse: what is the recommended way to make sure that a connection can be reused? Android documentation states the following:

> Once the response body has been read, the HttpURLConnection should be
>   closed by calling disconnect(). Disconnecting releases the resources
>   held by a connection so they may be closed or reused.

This implies that in order for the socket to be reused, `disconnect()` *should* be called.

However this seems to contradict other references in which I read that in order for the connection to be reused, the only resource that needs to be closed is the InputStream, and in fact disconnect() *should not* be called. This is also implied here: https://github.com/square/okhttp/issues/702

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It’s safe to call `disconnect()` on any thread, even while the HttpURLConnection is being used by another thread. This cancels the call but doesn’t release its resources.

If you created the HttpURLConnection you are obligated to close it when you’re done with it. The best way to do this is by closing the input stream or error stream. Which of these you get depends on the status code of the response.

Comment: Thank you Jesse, is it the same for all Android versions? or are there any issues on legacy versions that we should be aware of? (when calling disconnect() on any thread)

Comment: Different Android manufacturers to weird bad things in their devices. If you want full control over what’s in the wild, I recommend you bundle OkHttp with your app.

Comment: Thanks again, regarding my second question about the socket reuse, any thoughts or comments on that matter?

Comment: When you disconnect an HTTP/1 call in progress it tears down the socket and prevents reuse. If you disconnect after the call has completed it doesn't.